# PHP fread() Function Returning Extra Characters at the Front on UTF-8 Text Files

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, fread

While I'm using `fread()` on a normal text file (for example: ANSI file saved normally with Notepad), the returned content string is correct, as everyone knows.

But when I read the UTF-8 text file, the returning content string contains **invisible** characters (at the front). Why I said **invisible** is that the **extra characters** can't be seen normally on output (e.g.. `echo` for just read). But when the content string is used for processing (for example: Build a link with `href` value), problem is arisen then.

```
$filename = "blabla.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
echo '<a href="'.$contents.'">'.$contents.'</a>';
```

I put only `http://www.google.com` in the UTF-8 encoding text file. While running the PHP file, you will see a output link `http://www.google.com` 
.. but you will never reach to Google.

Because address source `href` is being like this:

```
%EF%BB%BFhttp://www.google.com
```

It means, `fread` added `%EF%BB%BF` weird characters at the front.

This is extra annoying stuff. Why it is happening?

*Added:*
Some pointing that is BOM. So, BOM or whatever, it is changing my original values. So now, it is problem with other steps, function calls, etc. Now I have to `substr($string,3)` for all outputs. This is totally non-sense changing the original values.

Comment: it think that;s the BOM signature you are seeing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the UTF-8 BOM. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

It is something that is optionally added to the beginnning of Utf-8 files, meaning it is in the file, and not something fread adds. Most text editors won't display the BOM, but some will -- mostly those that don't understand it. Not all editors will add it to Utf-8 files, but yet again, some will...

For Utf-8 the usage of BOM is not recommended, as it has no meaning and by many instances are not understood.

Comment: BOM or whatever, it is changing my original strings values. So now, it is problem with other steps, function calls. I have to `substr($string,3)` for all outputs. This is non-sense.

Comment: Please see josnidhin's excellent piece of code for a possible solution. You only have two options. (1) rewrite all your files to not include the BOM. (2) detect if the file has a BOM or not, and strip it upon file read.

Answer (score 3):

It is UTF-8 BOM. IF you look at the docs for fread([here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)) someone has discussed a solution for it.

The solution given over there is the following

```
// Reads past the UTF-8 bom if it is there.
function fopen_utf8 ($filename, $mode) {
    $file = @fopen($filename, $mode);
    $bom = fread($file, 3);
    if ($bom != b"\xEF\xBB\xBF")
        rewind($file, 0);
    else
        echo "bom found!\n";
    return $file;
}
```

Comment: Just `substr($string,3)` works bro, but i'm now so annoying over BOM.