# why the code can't update the content in the csv?

Tags: php

i want to remove the `Upload`, and change 0 to 888 in `qty` column,
the following is my code, it make the `csv` file content disordered. how to correct my code. thank you

```
 $dir   = getcwd();
   $files = scandir($dir);
   foreach ($files as $file)
   {
       $parts = pathinfo($file);
       if($parts['extension']!="csv") continue;
       if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE)
       {
           $new_content =  implode(',', fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))."\n";
           while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
           {
               $data[12]=substr($data[12],9);
               $data[13]=substr($data[13],9);
               $data[14]=substr($data[14],9);
               $data[42]=888;
               $new_content .= implode(',', $data)."\n";
           }
           fclose($handle);
        file_put_contents($file, $new_content);
       }
   }
```

the test csv file 
http://phplist.xxmn.com/women.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the first line of your .csv file is more than 1000 characters. If you're not sure ahead of time how big each line can be I would suggest this:

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ','); // >= PHP 5.0.4
```

Or

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ',');
```

The first option might slow down the processing, but it's probably going to be negligable.

You should also consider using `fputcsv` to write the output.

```
$dir   = getcwd();
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $parts = pathinfo($file);
   if ($parts['extension']!="csv") {
       continue;
   }
   if (false === ($outfile = fopen("$file.tmp", "w"))) {
       continue;
   }
   if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
       fputcsv($outfile, fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ","));

       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           $data[12]=substr($data[12],9);
           $data[13]=substr($data[13],9);
           $data[14]=substr($data[14],9);
           $data[42]=888;
           fputcsv($outfile, $data);
       }
       fclose($handle);
       fclose($outfile);
       if (false === rename("$file.tmp", $file)) {
           die("Could not rename temporary file");
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: when i changed 1000 to 0 or 4096. a new csv file can't work, you can give it a try.  http://phplist.xxmn.com/women.csv

Comment: phplist.xxmn.com/1.csv  this csv file also can't work, jack,do you know why? many thanks

Comment: updated my answer with some improvements that might work for you

Comment: it works, many thanks, but there is a line i can't understand it well. $outfile = fopen("$file.tmp", "w") could you explain it. thank you

Comment: It opens a file for writing; then afterwards, it renames this file to `$file` again.

Comment: your code is better better.. than me , you are my hero. many thanks

Comment: Jack, there is still a bug of it, if i want to exclude the header part(the 1st row of the csv file) how do i do?

Comment: If you want to exclude the header, you should replace `fputcsv($outfile, fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ","));` with just `fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",");`

Comment: Oh, and your CSV files have UTF-8 encoding I believe, which might cause those funny characters in the header.

Comment: if i don't want to exclude the header, is there a way to change the encoding character.

Comment: oh,no, the new csv file can't contain the header part. i need the header part. i want it don't generate unreadable character to the hearder.

Comment: Jack, is there a way to solve  those funny characters in the header

Comment: Yes, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126423/php-fread-function-returning-extra-charactors-at-the-front-on-utf-8-text-files

Comment: In your case, you can probably just do `fread($file, 3);` just after opening the file. Just make sure you don't run your script twice on the same file(s).

Comment: Jack,you php is gorgeous, could u tell me how to learn it. thank you :)

Comment: @run practice, practice, practice :)